# Airplay Discovery only working over wired connection not wifi, (once discovered over wired, works over wireless)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Ive got a network using Ubiquity UDM Pro (router), UDM switches and Nano HD access points.

The network was working fine, but recently has been preventing me from discovering some (but not all) airplay devices over wifi.

All airplay devices are on the same VLAN.

I can discover these airplay devices if i plug my computer into the wired network, but not over wifi.

Once these devices are discovered over wired connection, if i disconnect the wired connection and connect over wifi i can stream music to them over airplay via wifi.

All the devices have a mac to IP binding.

But after time / after the airplay device is rebooted they no longer appear and i have to re connect over a wired connection.

Ive tried enabling MDNS and enhanced MDNS, but to no avail. (all this did was show some airplay devices on other VLANS.. but not all airplay devices)

Im running the latest version of all unifi firmware as of the time of writing.

Any ideas what could be causing the issue and how i can resolve it ?

Comment: Does your router bridges WiFi and Ethernet? Meaning that both are on the same subnet/VLAN as the LAN. If the WiFi router supports both 2.4 & 5.1 GHz, try disabling one (perhaps the the 2.4) leaving only one option.

Comment: The wifi and ethernet are on the same subnet. I can infact via wifi visit the IP in a browser and ping the IP of the devices im having trouble with, its only when i try to airplay to them i have the issue

Comment: Are you using 5 or 2.4 GHz? The results might be better with 2.4 GHz.

Comment: @harrymc we have both enabled on the same SSID, i believe Unifi steers the clients to which ever it deems best. Im back on site tomorrow, ill try setting just 2.4, i dont really see the need for 5ghz.

Comment: @harrymc tried setting to 2.4ghz only, but no change unfortunately

Comment: How far apart are the devices? What's the route that wifi passes between them (meaning router & access points)? Note that Airplay is heavily criticized on the web for pour quality. I have seen this recommended: *Settings > General > AirPlay & Handoff > Automatically AirPlay to TVs*, change to Never.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by disabling Multicast/Broadcast filtering on my router/AP device (different brand of gear). It blocks chatty protocols at the wired/wireless border on my AP, even though they're the same subnet.

Other settings issues are usually multicast DNS being disabled like you've already looked at, or various vague optimization settings like "smart optimization" or "optimize for IOT devices" that can cause similar multicast/broadcast issues.

Another cause is lossy networks/wireless interference, especially with older wireless devices on 2.4GHz. mDNS is UDP, so it won't notice if discovery packets are getting dropped. This is less likely nowadays unless you notice your devices *are* getting discovered sometimes, or if you leave them searching for a while.

---

Otherwise, it may be time to break out the [packet captures](https://weberblog.net/apple-airplay-capture/), and see if devices on both wireless/wired are receiving mDNS (port 5353 UDP) queries and responses from each other. All of your [UniFi](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/227129127-UniFi-Methods-for-Capturing-Useful-Debug-Information#4) gear should have `tcpdump` available for this

Each device's in/out interface in the chain of AP/Switch/Router/etc should be checked if changing settings doesn't seem to work. Maybe you've got an AP that isn't actually respecting config updates for example